# how to show all post with relatedid in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

hey guys i have trouble in display all post with same relatedid and related id comes from qna and i want to show all relatedid post to qna_post.html please help to fix it in django 1.11 python3

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from qna.models import Post

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25], template_name="qna.html")),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model = Post, template_name= 'qna_post.html'))
]
```

qna_post.html
    {% extends "header.html" %}

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in object_list %}
{% url page_item item.id %}
    {% if post.relatedid == post.id %}
        {% if post.PostType == 'q' %}
            <h3>{{ post.Title }}</h3>
            <h6>on {{ post.date }}</h6>
            {{post.Body|safe|linebreaks}}
        {% endif %} 
        {% if post.PostType == 'a' %}
            <h3>{{ post.Title }}</h3>
            <h6>on {{ post.date }}</h6>
            {{post.Body|safe|linebreaks}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

qna.html

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in object_list %}
    {% if post.PostType == 'q' %}
    <h5>{{ post.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}<a href="/questions/{{ post.id }}"> {{ post.Title }}</a> -<label> {{ post.Body|slice:":8" }}...</label></h5>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```